# Is there a way to merge these two simple queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm sure I'm ridiculous for thinking it's possible but is there a way to merge these two queries?

**Query #1:**

```
select distinct 
    count(l.lease_id) as 'Count_Transactions_ALL', 
    sum(l.net_area) as 'Total_Area_ALL'
from
    lease_deal.lease l
where
    l.deal_approved_date >= @dateFrom   
    and l.deal_approved_date  <= @dateTo
    and l.lease_status in(@leaseStatus)
```

**Query #2:**

```
select distinct 
    count(l.lease_id) as 'Count_Transactions_NEW', 
from
    lease_deal.lease l
where
    l.deal_approved_date >= @dateFrom   
    and l.deal_approved_date  <= @dateTo
    and l.lease_status in(@leaseStatus)
    and l.negotiation_type = 'NEW'
```

My desired output would be:

Count_Transactions_ALL, Total_Area_All, Count_Transactions_NEW

x, y, z

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by "merging" them? You know that you can always write them as two sub-queries inside a query to return a single result set, right?

Comment: @zespri Educational curiosity

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
select 
    count(l.lease_id) as 'Count_Transactions_ALL', 
    sum(l.net_area) as 'Total_Area_ALL',
    sum(case l.negotiation_type 
        when 'NEW' then 1 else 0 end) 
    as Count_Transactions_NEW
from
    lease_deal.lease l
where
    l.deal_approved_date >= @dateFrom   
    and l.deal_approved_date  <= @dateTo
    and l.lease_status in(@leaseStatus)
```

Comment: what is the 'distinct' for in your query? It's not like it will ever return more than one row?

Comment: That's perfect, thank-you. Never quite thought about approaching the problem that way

Comment: @zespri touché sir, fixing now

Comment: @zespri, you're right. I just copied the original query and inserted the 'CASE' line. Fixing. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct 
        count(l.lease_id) as 'Count_Transactions_ALL', 
        sum(l.net_area) as 'Total_Area_ALL', 
       sum( if(l.negotiation_type = 'NEW', 1, 0)) as 'Count_Transactions_New'
    from
        lease_deal.lease l
    where
        l.deal_approved_date >= @dateFrom   
        and l.deal_approved_date  <= @dateTo
        and l.lease_status in(@leaseStatus)
```

Comment: This won't work. The `IF` wouldn't automatically `SUM` anything, meaning you wouldn't be aggregating anything.

Comment: It seems like it would work, but it adds an unnecessary additional function call (`IF`) in addition to the `SUM`. The `CASE` is evaluated in place instead.

Comment: at the risk of being pedantic: is case faster than if?

Comment: Yes, it is. It requires an additional function call, while `CASE is internal and is evaluated in place (as I said in my last comment). Note I didn't downvote your answer; I was just providing info.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7183/discussion-between-startup007-and-ken-white)